# Batch rename files in sequence

Tags: shell, rename

I am having trouble renaming image sequences in the shell.

I have about 300 files following the pattern `myimage_001.jpg` and I would like to transform that to `myimage.0001.jpg` where the numbers increment with each file.

This is what I have tried with no success (the `-n` flag being there to show the result before actually applying it):

```
rename -n 's/_/./g' *.jpg
```

Comment: What happened when you ran this?

Comment: What system is this on?  My system doesn't have `rename`.

Comment: Nothing happened. I am thinking my system does not have it either. I found that command on SO while searching before posting. I run Linux SL6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this command :**

```
rename _ . *.jpg
```

**Example :**

```
> touch myimage_001.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle oinstall      0 Mar 17 10:55 myimage_001.jpg
> rename  _ . *.jpg
> ll
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle oinstall      0 Mar 17 10:55 myimage.001.jpg
```

**With an extra 0 :**

```
> touch myimage_001.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle oinstall      0 Mar 17 10:55 myimage_001.jpg
> rename  _ .0 *.jpg
> ll
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle oinstall      0 Mar 17 10:55 myimage.0001.jpg
```

**the syntax is simple :**

```
rename 'old' 'new' 'data-source'
```

Comment: This will not work with the `perl` implementation of rename that OP uses.

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth - can explain why ? - it worked for me always !

Comment: I don't know why but this worked event though it did not and a 0. This is not problem and I can work with files being myimage.###.jpg. Thank you very much

Comment: Is there a waqy to add a 0 ? To have the end file be myimage.0001.jpg instead of myimage.001.jpg ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not familiar enough with the shell to have an imagination ;)

That worked though, Thanks !

Comment: yeah ! that was a mean comment from my part :), sorry ! Happy to help !

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me? Note however that this does not add an additional leading zero like in your question, was this a typo?

```
$ find
.
./myimage_001.jpg
./myimage_007.jpg
./myimage_006.jpg
./myimage_002.jpg
./myimage_004.jpg
./myimage_009.jpg
./myimage_008.jpg
./myimage_003.jpg
./myimage_005.jpg

$ rename -n 's/_/./g' *.jpg
myimage_001.jpg renamed as myimage.001.jpg
myimage_002.jpg renamed as myimage.002.jpg
myimage_003.jpg renamed as myimage.003.jpg
myimage_004.jpg renamed as myimage.004.jpg
myimage_005.jpg renamed as myimage.005.jpg
myimage_006.jpg renamed as myimage.006.jpg
myimage_007.jpg renamed as myimage.007.jpg
myimage_008.jpg renamed as myimage.008.jpg
myimage_009.jpg renamed as myimage.009.jpg

$ rename 's/_/./g' *.jpg
$ find
.
./myimage.008.jpg
./myimage.007.jpg
./myimage.001.jpg
./myimage.003.jpg
./myimage.006.jpg
./myimage.005.jpg
./myimage.002.jpg
./myimage.009.jpg
./myimage.004.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```
for file in *.jpg; do 
    name="${file%_*}" 
    num="${file#*_}"
    num="${num%.*}"
    ext="${file#*.}"
    mv "$file" "$(printf "%s.%04d.%s" $name $num $ext)"
done
```

This gives:

```
$ ls
myimage_001.jpg  myimage_002.jpg
```

```
$ for file in *.jpg; do 
  name="${file%_*}" 
  num="${file#*_}"
  num="${num%.*}"
  ext="${file#*.}"
  mv "$file" "$(printf "%s.%04d.%s" $name $num $ext)"
done
```

```
$ ls
myimage.0001.jpg  myimage.0002.jpg
```

Comment: Even though I have a found a solution thanks to a user on this post, I would be curious to try this out. How would I change the command to have my end file be : myimage.####.jpg ?

Comment: @titatom I didnt not follow. This command will rename `myimage_001.jpg` to `myimage.0001.jpg` is there something else you want?

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative:

```
$ touch a.txt  b.txt  c.txt  d.txt  e.txt  f.txt
$ ls
a.txt  b.txt  c.txt  d.txt  e.txt  f.txt
```

We can use `ls` combined with `sed` + `xargs` to achieve your goal.

```
$ ls | sed -e "p;s/\.txt$/\.sql/"|xargs -n2 mv

$ ls
a.sql  b.sql  c.sql  d.sql  e.sql  f.sql
```

See http://nixtip.wordpress.com/2010/10/20/using-xargs-to-rename-multiple-files/ for detailed information.